# Trying to read data from Hadoop URL but unable to do so.I am getting error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

The Contents of the ReadFromHadoopURL file are as follows:

```
package com.felix.hadoop.training;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;

//  URLCat
public class ReadFromHadoopURL {

  static {
        URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
      in = new URL(args[0]).openStream();
      IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
    } finally {
      IOUtils.closeStream(in);
    }
      }
    }
```

Then I created a jar file ReadFromHadoopURL.jar .

Then I ran this command

```
hadoop jar /home/training/Pradosh/ReadFromHadoopURL.jar ReadFromHadoopURL hdfs://localhost:54310/my/empfile
```

I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ReadFromHadoopURL
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

Could you please help me to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to fully qualify your class name with the package name.  `ReadFromHadoopURL` should be `com.felix.hadoop.training.ReadFromHadoopURL`.

```
hadoop jar /home/training/Pradosh/ReadFromHadoopURL.jar com.felix.hadoop.training.ReadFromHadoopURL hdfs://localhost:54310/my/empfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .You are right there.I did that. But now when I am running I am getting this error....

Comment: When I am trying to write the whole error. it's telling exceeding the comment length.Could you please tell me how to post it?

Answer (score 0):

To run with the `hadoop jar` command, you have to implement a class containing `Map extends Mapper<>` class (and optionally `Reduce extends Reducer<>`) as illustrated in the canonical [WordCount Example](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount).

The above looks like you're trying to implement a simple Java console app to cat a file stored in HDFS.  If that's the case then you should run it with something like:

`java -cp ./ReadFromHadoopURL.jar ReadFromHadoopURL hdfs://localhost:54310/my/empfile`

Note: getting all of the Hadoop and Apache dependencies to work from the command line will likely require a much expanded cp/classpath.

Comment: This isn't true.  You don't have to have a Mapper to run an application that interacts with Hadoop.  Also, one of the main functions of the `hadoop jar` command is to set up the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` with the core dependencies you need for Hadoop applications.

Comment: Good correction.  I hadn't used `hadoop jar` that way before.  I can get it to run a simple hello world, but I get large number of errors like `java.lang.Exception: 2012-02-03 19:11:02 SampleClass8 [WARN] problem finding id 153454612 at com.osa.mocklogger.MockLogger$2.run(MockLogger.java:83)` when running code similar to Pradosh.  Not sure if the problem is specific to my cluster config or if he's hitting something like that as well.

Comment: That warning doesn't seem Hadoop related